# Image Upload and Preview Option, Code Not Allowing For Distinct Images To Display

Tags: javascript, html, image, upload, image-uploading

So I'm working on a site for a client. The area in question I need help with is an upload and preview area for photos. The photos don't need to be transmitted in this process, this is JUST to upload and preview in comparison to an example--for a dental clinic.

There are 5 example photos and 5 upload sections where they would preview the photo next to the example.

The code I'm using is:

```
<style>
    /* Image Designing Propoerties */
    .thumb {
        height: 75px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* The uploader form */
    $(function () {
        $(":file").change(function () {
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });

    function imageIsLoaded(e) {
        $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#yourImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

</script>


<input type='file' />
</br><img id="myImg" src="#" alt="your image" height=247 width=330>
```

So here's the kicker. When I use this code for one code block (built on a Squarespace platform) it will upload and display a photo for that block no problem.

When I add it to other areas, the upload destination either changes to a different area or, tweaking it I've gotten two blocks to display the same image but I'm not sure how to write it so each block displays its own image and I'm not sure what I'm overlooking ID or SRC wise that would trigger that.

If needed, I'll gladly send over the link and site password for further examination. Thanks in advance, first time using stackoverflow help chat.

Comment: Platform in question for client is Squarespace. Any and all help appreciated I’ve tweaked it a few times but i can’t find my error and solution.

Comment: your js code is not previewing image! Can use my own code for previewing image ?

Comment: On my end when it’s plugged in the image will preview, but if I add in another code block it and upload a different image it just shows the same or changes the first code block. It’s like it doesn’t recognize it distinctly as it’s own

Comment: if my answer was helpful then mark it accepted by clicking tick https://drive.google.com/open?id=1A_aTMwRDwYXFa-xcnXVt2g0kTIiRgmrR

Answer (score 0):

I just created a `function readurl(a)`   to which i am passing a parameter `a`. This parameter will tell the funcion about `id` of `input` and and `id` of `img` where we want to preview the image. Because the ids of all `elements` in `html` should be different.

**HTML & JS Code**

```js
function readurl(a) 
{
    input=document.getElementById('input'+a);
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) 
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) 
        {
            document.getElementById('blah'+a).src=e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="new_img_container" >
        <label id="file">Upload image
        <input onchange="readurl(1)" id="input1" name="product_img" type="file" name="image" size="60" required>
        </label>
        <br>
        <img id="blah1" src="../images/product_image.png" alt="product_image" >
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="new_img_container" >
        <label id="file">Upload image
        <input onchange="readurl(2)" id="input2" name="product_img" type="file" name="image" size="60" required>
        </label>
        <br>
        <img id="blah2" src="../images/product_image.png" alt="product_image" >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't added any CSS for styling.